# How to make an async then?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Basically I am trying to play around to understand more of `async/await` and `promise` in `JS`. I'm trying to make **Hello** comes in between **finished!** and **third finish!!**. So the best guess is, making second `then` asnyc and await for `console.log('Hello')`. I've tried both ways below but both are not working as expected.

**Approach A**

```js
let promise = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  res();
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('finished!')
}).then(() => {
  setTimeout(async function(){     
    await console.log("Hello"); }, 3000); //async/await at setTimeout level
}).then(() => {
  console.log('third finish!!')
})
```

**Approach B:**

```js
let promise = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      res();
    });

    promise.then(() => {
      console.log('finished!')
    }).then(async () => { //async/await at thenlevel
      await setTimeout(function(){     
        console.log("Hello"); }, 3000); 
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('third finish!!')
    })
```

Comment: `await console.log` makes no sense since, a) console.log is synchronous, and b) it doesn't return a promise anyway - as for your question, the result of `.then` is guaranteed to be a promise, so, is asynchronous by definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the second section to be a `Promise`, and return it from the `.then` so that it's properly chained between the first and the third. `setTimeout` doesn't return a `Promise`, you have to explicitly construct a `Promise` instead:

```js
let promise = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  res();
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('finished!')
}).then(() => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function(){     
      console.log("Hello");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('third finish!!')
})
```

Or, using `await`, use `await new Promise` followed by the same Promise construction and the `setTimeout`:

```js
let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res();
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('finished!')
}).then(async() => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("Hello");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}).then(() => {
  console.log('third finish!!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to write an asynchronous `setAsyncTimeout` function (this hasn't been thoroughly tested, may need tweaks):

```
async function setAsyncTimeout(callback, interval) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            try {
                let inner = callback()
                if (inner && inner.then) {
                    inner.then(resolve, reject)
                } else {
                    resolve(inner)
                }
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e)
            }
        }, interval)
    })
}
```

---

## Testing via your example:

```
let promise = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  res();
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('finished!')
}).then( setAsyncTimeout(function(){     
    console.log("Hello"); }, 3000); 
}).then(() => {
  console.log('third finish!!')
})
```

---

## Testing via your example (with another promise):

```
let promise = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  res();
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('finished!')
}).then(async () => { //async/await at thenlevel
  await setAsyncTimeout(function(){     
    console.log("Hello");
    return setAsyncTimeout(() => console.log("world"), 3000)
  }, 3000); 
}).then(() => {
  console.log('third finish!!')
})
```

---

## Cleaner example:

```
let promise = new Promise((res,rej)=>{
  res();
});

promise.then(() => {
  console.log('finished!')
}).then(() => {
  return setAsyncTimeout(() => { console.log("Hello"); }, 3000)
}).then(() => {
  console.log('third finish!!')
})
```

Comment: Correct me if I understanding it wrongly but it seems to me that underlying it works exactly same as @CertainPerformance 's answer?

Comment: @Isaac our names are going to confuse onlookers. Yes, the result is the same, it just depends on whether you're looking to refactor the code or whether the inlined setTimeout is simple enough