# Continuous async/await with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I'm new at ES6, so I study statement of Javascript.

While testing of async/await, I found some strange behavior.

I wrote the code like this,

```
const test = async () => {
    await setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("timeout");
    }, 2000);
    await console.log(1);
    await console.log(2);
}

test();
```

Output is here,

```
1
2
timeout
[Finished in 2.1s]
```

I define async to function and await to every line to work synchronize.

Expected output is here,

```
timeout
1
2
[Finished in 2.1s]
```

Why this code doesn't work synchronize?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't `await setTimeout` (meaningfully) because `setTimeout` does not return a `Promise`.

Comment: `async/await` is syntactic sugar for working with *promises*. If the function doesn't return a promise then `await` doesn't really help. `await setTimeout()` has the same effect as `setTimeout()`. [Read the MDN documentation about `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: You can't await console.log either.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks. So how can I fix that code to works properly?

Comment: Make a function that returns a `Promise` instead. (or just `await` a `Promise`)

Comment: Create a function that calls `setTimeout` and returns a promise.

Comment: @Hide: You can check for answer @ question that I've recently asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237862/how-to-make-an-async-then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you can achieve the desired output. You can wrap your `setTimeout` in a `Promise` and `await` it.

```js
const test = async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("timeout");
        resolve();
    }, 2000)); 
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
}

test();
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: There isn't really any reason to wrap `console.log` in a promise though... *"You can only `await` on Promises"* That's not true. You can `await` any value. But if it's not a promise it just returns the value immediately.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'll update my answer

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for a clear answer.

Comment: But you can't `await console.log` either. So probably remove the both useless `await` too lol

Comment: @Isaac, what do you mean you CAN'T `await console.log`? `await console.log('hello world')` prints `hello world` immediately.